# apt update_cache not valid for next task

Tags: ansible, apt-get

Take the following playbook snippet:

```yaml
  - name: remove unattended-upgrades 
    apt:
      name: unattended-upgrades
      update_cache: yes
      state: absent

  - name: misc packages
    apt:
      name:
        - qperf
        - fio
      state: present
```

I get a failure on the second task, which installs `qperf` and `fio`, because the package could not be found. The underlying cause is that apt hasn't had `apt-get update` run, as I do not have `update_cache: yes` in configuration. However, the previous task, which removes a package, *does* have `update_cache: yes` and tasks run in order, so why doesn't this work?

Comment: It indeed contradicts [_Run the equivalent of `apt-get update` before the operation. Can be run as part of the package installation or as a separate step._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-update_cache) Would you mind sharing your Ansible verison?

Comment: Also a thing you could try is to decouple the `update_cache: yes` fully in an `apt` task on its own, and see how this reacts.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε it is `ansible [core 2.11.6]`.